# Java don't read in pictures and audio files with relative path

Tags: java, jar, relative-path

In java i programmed a small program to play audio file and sow pictures:
At first i make a final String with the path and then i made a file object.
At least i save the returned array in my "tracks" variable.
This is my code:

```
private static final String PATH = "../src/audio/";
private static final File FILE = new File(PATH);
tracks = liesAudioDateien(file);

private AudioClip[] liesAudioDateien (File inputFile) {
    File[] dateFileArray;
    AudioClip[] tracks;
    dateFileArray = inputFile.listFiles();
    tracks = new AudioClip[dateFileArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        if (dateFileArray[i].isFile()) {
            try {
                tracks[i] = Applet.newAudioClip(dateFileArray[i].toURL());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Oops!: -- " + ex.toString());
            }
        }

    }
    return tracks;
```

If I run this code, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at source.Sound.liesAudioDateien(Sound.java:32)
```

Sound.java:32:
This is `tracks = new AudioClip[dateFileArray.length];` line.

If i try with an absolute path, it does work!
What i do wrong?

Comment: At first only for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"../src/audio/"` to `"./src/audio/"`

Comment: Yes, it does work in NetBeans, but it doesn't work if i make a jar. :(

Comment: Make sure while making jar(If you are bundling it with jar) read this file using ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName).

Comment: Can you explain your answer please! I'm a new java programmer

Comment: @hydroid : "." means current directory path. In the project the current directory path is always your main project folder path

Comment: Ok. If I understad what you want to show, then i should make my

Answer (score 0):

Your path is relative, which is resolved to be relative to the current working directory. The current working directory is not what you think it is.

Try to do this before `inputFile.listFiles()`;

```
System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

And see what Java *thinks* the absolute path should be.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful! I try it today!

Answer (score 0):

[`File.listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) returns `null` if the abstract pathname does not denote a directory.

You need to make sure `inputFile` *does* denote a directory to ensure `dateFileArray` is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with File.separator in place of forward/backward slash. 
ex:

```
String soundDir = "." + File.separator + "folderName" + File.separator;
String fileName = "sound.wav";
String filePath = soundDir+ + fileName;
```